# CWEB @<100 ms. service@>=+

Tags: c, embedded

I am tasked to optimize some old code, that was for some reason written in CWEB language. I have never worked with CWEB before and it is quite confusing.

A part of it I would like to ask you about:

```
@ 100 ms. service.

@<100 ms. service@>=+
```

This is features in the code, but I am not exactly sure what it does.
Is it true that the code following this runs every 100 ms.? If so, how do i make it so it only runs once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you show us here, is no C code and not related to C language. CWEB is not C but a system creating C code.

Comment: The name `100 ms. service` is just that — a name used by the author to convey intent.  It is probably intended that the code is run every 100 ms, but the name does not guarantee that is what happens.  You'll need to look at what the code is after the `=+` part is, and where it is called from.